# Get a link to image attached to telegram message using telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon, telegram-api

I am writing an app in Python for interacting with Telegram API using Telethon.
I iterate over messages and **if a message has an image I would like to return a link to this image to frontend**, to display it there.

I can't figure out how to do this, since non of the fields in `MessageMediaPhoto` seem to be useful for this:

```
'media': {
     '_': 'MessageMediaPhoto',
     'spoiler': False,
     'photo': {
         '_': 'Photo',
         'id': 5352682467171094367,
         'access_hash': 8073060746959213931,
         'file_reference': b'\x02J\xf3q\xa5\x00\x00\x10\xf8e\x18\x1f\x10\xf3Za\xe5(\xa1\xde)\x14\xbe\x07&\xab\xcc\xbb\xbe',
         'date': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 1, 15, 31, 12, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
         'sizes': [{'_': 'PhotoStrippedSize', 'type': 'i', 'bytes': b'\x01\x19(\xa8\xc7\xb6\x057+\x8ez\xfd)\xed\x9e\xf4\x82\x02\xe8\\\x129\xc7\x15L,E\xc3t\xa7"\xe7>\xd4\xa6\x13\x10\x19\xef@;O\x14\x00\xf1\xc3\xaf\xd6\x8a`r\xd2/\xd6\x8a.\x03\x8e;T\xb0N\xd1&\x06\xd23\x9eEANO\xbbOt\x04\x93\xcce# q\xe8*\xbbT\xf5\x04\x9fz\x93\xd1\x03\x1a\x9f\xeb\x17\xea(\xa5O\xf5\x8b\xf5\x14R\x03'}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'm', 'w': 320, 'h': 200, 'size': 13799}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'x', 'w': 800, 'h': 500, 'size': 58069}, {'_': 'PhotoSizeProgressive', 'type': 'y', 'w': 1280, 'h': 800, 'sizes': [8921, 19838, 35053, 50009, 81376]}],
         'dc_id': 2,
         'has_stickers': False,
         'video_sizes': []
        },
        'ttl_seconds': None
    }
```

Here is the current code that I have

```
async def get_news_from_tg():
    channel = await client.get_entity(channel_link)
    async for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reply_to=reviews_root_id, limit=10):
      print(message.to_dict())
```

I tried opening direct image addresses from telegram clients, but it doesn't seem that any of the API returned info could help me to construct one.

Comment: Telegram doesn't use http or "links", it has its own protocol and files are all encrypted. you can only download the Photo or any other media for your frontend. read about [download_media](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_media) and pass it the `Photo` object.

Comment: When you say frontend you mean you want a link to be able to download it? Or do you want it to simply display the image? Or just highlight the position in the channel/group where the image exists?

Comment: @PaulRandleman Simply to display the image on website